# Android picture saved to internal storage is the thumbnail

Tags: android

I made a class to take and save pictures to internal storage, but the the problem is i save thumbnail and not full sized photo.

This is the class :

```
public class PhotoManager {

private final static String DEBUG_TAG = "PHOTOMANAGER";
private String mCurrentPhotoPath = "";
private String filePath = "";
private Intent takePictureIntent;
private Activity activity;
private String type;
private int Q_ID;
private PhotoCallbackListener mListener;
private FragmentManager fragManager;

public void setListener(PhotoCallbackListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public PhotoManager(Activity activity, int Q_ID, String type, FragmentManager fm, PhotoCallbackListener listener) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.Q_ID = Q_ID;
    this.type = type;
    this.mListener = listener;
    this.fragManager = fm;
}
// init la vue de la camera
public void init(){
    dispatchTakePictureIntent(11);
}
// affiche la camera
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(final int actionCode) {


    Fragment f = new Fragment() {
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                     Intent data) {
            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // efface la photo créee de la galerie
                activity.getContentResolver().delete(data.getData(), null, null);
            }

        }
    };
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.fragManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(f, "getpicture");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}

private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) throws IOException {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

    File f = createImageFile();
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

    filePath = saveToInternalStorage(mImageBitmap);

    galleryAddPic();

    mListener.callback(mImageBitmap, filePath);

}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"createImageFile");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(0));
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + "_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            null //default location for temporary files
    );
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"return "+image.getAbsolutePath());

    return image;
}

private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(activity.getApplicationContext());

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"saveToInternalStorage");

    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir_"+type, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String fileName = "q"+Q_ID+".jpg";
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath = new File(directory, fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"return "+directory.getAbsolutePath());
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}



private void galleryAddPic() {
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,contentUri);
    activity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
}
```

I use it like this :

```
pm = new PhotoManager(getActivity(), Q_ID, getArguments().getString("type"), fm, new PhotoCallbackListener() {
        @Override
        public void callback(Bitmap mImageBitmap, String file) {

            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
            filePath = file;

        }

    });

 Button buttonPhoto = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.q4BtnPhoto);
    buttonPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pm.init();
        }

    });
```

I return the bitmap thumbnail to put it in the layout, and the filePath just for test.

Can anyone help me to understand why the full sized photo is not saved ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by myself :

I made a big mistake, i saved the thumbnail to internal storage not the full sized.

in the method handleSmallCameraPhoto i can get the full sized saved image with :

```
Uri fullsizeImage = intent.getData();
```

I get the bitmap of the image like this :

```
Bitmap mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), fullsizeImage);
```

Then after i call my saveToInternalStorage method.

Comment: It's always nice when you can solve your own problem. And thanks for posting your own answer, it might save someone else from a question later on.